# Compiling a Haxe Flash application to Adobe AIR using OpenFL

Tags: flash, haxe, openfl, haxelib

I am doing support for a company that has a business app written in `haxe` that compiles to `Flash` `swf`. The application is a layout generator that loads a list of items that can then be dragged onto the layout. The list of items are loaded from a `PHP` server using `AMFPHP`.

What we are looking at is porting this application to `Adobe AIR` so that we can continue using this application after 2020. After doing some research, I discovered the [`Lime/OpenFL`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=openfl.lime-vscode-extension) `VSCode` extension and thought that the best route would be to try get the `haxe` code to compile to `AIR` using `Lime`. I have not had any experience with using `haxe` or with `Flash` or `OpenFL` development, so this is all very new to me, and I do not know to what extent this port is feasible. So my first question is very broad, but I am wanting to know if anyone has had experience with doing  conversions like this, and who might be able to comment on the feasibility of this approach?

To give a bit more detail about the application, here is the `build.hxml` that gets used to compile the current `Flash` application:

```
-cp Source
-D LOCAL_TEST
-D haxe-boot
-D flash-use-stage
-swf-lib index.swf
-swf-version 9
-swf pdfbuilder.swf
-debug
PDFBuilder
```

The `index.swf` gets compiled separately using `mxmlc` and is just a number of components made using `Flex`.  So my next question regarding this port is whether I would be able to include this `index.swf` as is when I compile to `AIR`?

I have `Haxe 4.0` installed; I have created an `OpenFL` project in `VSCode` and have tried to compile it.  I am getting a number of error messages, the main two being that the import of `haxe.remoting.AMFConnection` fails with a *type not found* error, and the application does not have a *Main* type, because the startup of a `Flash` application is clearly different.

I am not exactly sure how to change the startup; the current application startup is as follows:

```
class PDFBuilder {
    // CONFIG
    inline public static var _hostAddress = #if LOCAL_TEST 'http://212.45.52.43' #else '' #end;
    inline public static var _hostLocalPath = 'C:/Inetpub/wwwroot';
    public static var _userPath:String;

    /** Reference to Main Flex Application object **/
    public static var flex:Dynamic;

    public static var app:PDFBuilder;
    public static var event:PDFBuilderEvents;

    public static var service = AMFConnection.urlConnect(#if LOCAL_TEST _hostAddress +
        '/commonfiles/php/amfphp-1.2/gateway.php' #else 'amfphp-1.2/gateway.php' #end);

    // Layout items container
    public static var itemData:ItemData = new ItemData(updateItemTreeData);

    public var grid:layout.Grid;
    public var events:PDFBuilderEvents;
    public var uploader:UploadManager;

    public function main(_flex:Dynamic) {
        app = this;

        ....
```

`Lime` I believe is expecting a *Main* class rather than a class name that reflects the name of the application (*PDFBuilder*), but I am sure there are more things that need to change besides the name of the class.

Answer (score 2):

Use --library argument in your hxml file: https://haxe.org/manual/compiler-usage.html

For haxe4 I think you need to use air4 lib https://lib.haxe.org/p/air4haxe/